# Convert a list comprehension to functional programming

Tags: python, dictionary, functional-programming, python-itertools

I have a list of dictionaries

```
lst = [{'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (2, 3)},
       {'c': (3, 6), 'd': (4, 8), 'e': (5, 10)},
       {'d': (6, 12), 'e': (7, 14)}]
```

For each key in each dictionary, I want to keep only the first element of the values. So the desired output is

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}, {'d': 6, 'e': 7}]
```

I can get it using a list comprehension like

```
[{key: val[0] for key, val in dct.items()} for dct in lst]
```

However, I want to know if it's possible to get the same output using map, itemgetter, itertools, functools etc. What I have so far:

```
map(dict.values, lst)
```

But I don't know how to go from here.

Comment: Well, there is no function I could think of that does exactly what you need. If you write such a function, perhaps composed of other functions, then you can `map` it over the list, sure…

Comment: Note that [comprehensions are perfectly fine for functional programming](https://wiki.haskell.org/List_comprehension).

Comment: A list comprehension **is a functional programming construct**, stolen directly from the rather hardcore, purely functional programming language Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For nested iterations, I don't think we can do it without the help of lambda expressions:

```
from operator import itemgetter, methodcaller

list(map(
     lambda items: dict(zip(
             map(itemgetter(0), items),
             map(itemgetter(0), map(itemgetter(1), items))
         )), map(methodcaller('items'), lst)))
# [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}, {'d': 6, 'e': 7}]
```

I have to say it's very ugly.

**Update:**
I found a way to avoid lambda:

1. First, according to the comment area, we simplify the above expression (the outermost list is omitted here to reduce the difficulty of understanding):

```
func = lambda d: dict(zip(d, map(itemgetter(0), d.values())))
map(func, lst)
```

2. It is easy to observe that `dict` can be moved outside lambda. We just need to add another `map`:

```
func = lambda d: zip(d, map(itemgetter(0), d.values()))
map(dict, map(func, lst))
```

3. Similarly, we can move the `zip` outside lambda:

```
func = lambda d: map(itemgetter(0), d.values())
map(dict, map(zip, lst, map(func, lst)))
```

4. This seems to be the end, and there seems to be no way to convert lambda into a combination of multiple built-in functions, but there are still ways, let's first try to move `d.values` outside lambda. Here, since the element type of the list is determined, we directly use `dict.values` instead of `operator.methodcaller`:

```
func = lambda values: map(itemgetter(0), values)
map(dict, map(zip, lst, map(func, map(dict.values, lst))))
```

5. The answer is ready to come out. We can eliminate lambda by using `functools.partial`:

```
map(dict, map(zip, lst, map(partial(map, itemgetter(0)), map(dict.values, lst))))
```

Test:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> from functools import partial
>>> lst = [{'a': (1, 2, 3), 'b': (2, 3)},
...        {'c': (3, 6), 'd': (4, 8), 'e': (5, 10)},
...        {'d': (6, 12), 'e': (7, 14)}]
>>> map(dict, map(zip, lst, map(partial(map, itemgetter(0)), map(dict.values, lst))))
<map object at 0x000002A0542CBB20>
>>> list(_)
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}, {'d': 6, 'e': 7}]
```

Comment: I think you could reduce the complexity a bit: `list(map(lambda d: dict(zip(d, map(itemgetter(0), methodcaller("values")(d)))), lst))`?

Comment: @Timus In that case, we might as well change `methodcaller("values")(d)` directly to `d.values()`

Comment: Indeed, but I wanted to keep it as _functional_ as possible (not saying this is good practice) :)

Comment: If I understood your solution correctly, you're getting the first element of each dictionary and constructing a new dictionary for each dictionary, correct? Do you think there is a way to do the same without lambda, like is there a function in some module that facilitates such operation?

Comment: @DarthSkywalker You seem to have misunderstood. I took out all the items of each dictionary, with the key of each dictionary as the new key and the first element of the value as the new value.

Comment: @DarthSkywalker There seems to be no way to convert all the items of each dictionary into a series of new dictionaries without the help of lambda expression.

Comment: I think using `zip` here is just making it harder to get at what you want

Comment: @DarthSkywalker why? The whole *point* of functional programming is to write and use functions. There is no built-in function to do this in Python. Note, Python is very much *not* a functional programming language, so even if that were a reasonable built-in convenience function for a functional programming language to have, it certainly wouldn't mean that you'd expect to find it in Python.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga There are a lot of answers on here that suggest that mapping a builtin function (without lambda) is faster than list comprehension and I was wondering if it was possible to do it in this case. I'm just learning this stuff and I don't even know if I used the correct terminology (re: functional programming) but I found your comments very informative. Thank you.

Comment: @DarthSkywalker that isn't really true. Sometimes it is, but the difference in *either case* is usually not a relevant factor, especially as the work done in the mapping operation increases. `map` vs list-comprehension is a matter of style. Same in relation to just a regular for-loop. Write code to be clear, maintainable, modular, and not obviously inefficient (e.g. using a quadratic time algorithm when a linear time one is trivial)

Comment: Slight alternative: `map(dict, map(zip, lst, map(map, repeat(itemgetter(0)), map(dict.values, lst))))` (I actually came up with that independently and was delighted that we came up with almost the same, although I'd say it's rather straightforward and thus not very surprising :-)